# Import multiple datasets, then plot separately

Tags: plotting, data, visualization

First of all, I am pretty inexperienced with Mathematica. I am using it for data analysis for a lab class.

I have a file folder with my data as tab-separated values in .txt files. They are named data_##.txt. I would like to mass import the data into Mathematica, and then generate a ListPlot for each dataset. I don't need to do any analysis on the datasets--just visual inspection of the graphs.

Here is what I tried:

```
allData=Import["filepath\data_*", "Table"]
```

This generates

```
allData={{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}, {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}}
```

which is what I expected/wanted to happen. Each dataset is its own list of {x,y} values. Now I need to plot each dataset on a separate plot. When I use

```
ListPlot[alldata]
```

it plots all the datasets on the same graph. I understand why that is but I'm wondering if there's a way to quickly plot all the datasets with the way I've imported them. Right now I've just done

```
ListPlot[alldata [[a]]]
```

for each set (a = 1, 2, 3, etc). This works, but I feel like there should be a way to do this automatically.

Comment: See [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html). `ListPlot /@ allData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like

```
Do[
  ListPlot[set]//Print
,{set,allData}]
```

This will do the following: since `allData` is a list of lists `{set,allData}` will iterate over all of them and you can do whatever you want with each individual `set`, e.g., plot it. Note, however, that within a `Do` loop you'll need to specify `//Print` in order to get visual output.